# Doubt regarding the projection along new basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am trying to solve the following problem.
As per my understanding, the scalar projection of $\vec{p}$ along $\vec{b}1$  should be

### $\vec{p}$ . $\vec{b}1$ / |$\vec{b}1$|

Then why do we divide by |$\vec{b}1$| twice? To get the correct answer we need to use the following formula instead, but why:

### $\vec{p}$ . $\vec{b}1$ / |$\vec{b}1$||$\vec{b}1$|

[image]

Comment: You are correct about the formula for the scalar projection, but the scalar projection is different from the coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the formula above, I would say:

$v = c_1 b_1 + c_2 b_2\\
c_1 + c_2 = 5\\
c_1 - c_2 = -1$

And now I have a rather simple system of equations.

At a deeper level of understanding, I might say:

$T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ would be a transformation from the basis $B$ to the standard basis.

In which chase $T^{-1}v$ would transform v in the standard basis to the basis $B.$

As for what you have in your formula above.

We take $b_1$ and we normalize it.

i.e. $u_1 = \frac {b_1}{\|b_1\|}$

Then we calculate the dot product.

$v\cdot u_1$ giving us a magnitude in this direction.  Multiply by the direction vector

$(v\cdot u_1) u_1$

Substituting back

$(v\cdot u_1) u_1$ = $(v\cdot \frac {b_1}{\|b_1\|}) \frac {b_1}{\|b_1\|} = \frac {v\cdot b_1}{\|b_1\|^2}b_1$